# Getting CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE is [0,0] on Nexus 6P

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to figure out setting manual exposure compensation on camera2 API. As I understand I need to query `CameraCharacteristics` for `CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE` and as long as `CONTROL_AE_MODE` is `ON` I should be able to get a range. However, all I'm getting is [0,0] which either means the device doesn't support exposure compensation (which is unlikely) or I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried specifically setting the following on my `mPreviewRequestBuilder`:

```
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
```

after which I set the repeating request:

```
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null,
                mBackgroundHandler);
```

I'm trying to get the range using:

```
        Range <Integer> range = mCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus 6P doesn't currently support exposure compensation, so what you're seeing is correct.

We hope to fix this in the future.